# How to fix Android tab panel in order not to call onCreateView of next tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabpanel

I have an Android application. After I login I have a main activity page which contains 3 tab panels. These 3 panels are fragmented. I have overridden onCreateView for all and I filled onCreateView method in second and third panel and I am calling my service to fill my spinner.

After I login, while I am at the first fragment the onCreateView method of second fragment starts to work and calls the service.

Then when I passed the second tab, third onCreateView of third fragment starts to work and calls the service.

I don't understand this situation.How to overcome this.

Is there a reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: Do you use a viewpager?It's normal.If it don't load the second fragment.When you swipe to left,What will you see?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.Yes I am using a viewpager.Well you say it is normal.You are right at this point.I am using viewpager first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal for viewpager load next fragment when you in first fragment.

You can use fragment below to lazyload:

```
public abstract class LazyFragment extends Fragment {
    protected boolean isVisible;
    private boolean loaded = false;

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(getUserVisibleHint()&&!loaded) {
            loaded = true;
            isVisible = true;
            onVisible();
        } else {
            isVisible = false;
        }
    }
    protected void onVisible(){
        lazyLoad();
    }
    protected abstract void lazyLoad();
}

public class YourFragment extends LazyFragment{
    public void lazyload(){
       //do thing you want to do when you turn to this page.
    }
}
```